# html5 video play issue in android 4.2

Tags: android, html, html5-video

I am creating an app with a WebView thats supposed to play a mp4 video using html5 "video" tag.

This is simple html5 code which is working fine in browser but not in android

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
</head> 
<body> 
<video  id="vd1" src="path/video.mp4" type="video/mp4" width="100%" height="100%"  loop >
</video>
<script type="text/javascript">

var vid = document.getElementById("vd1");
if(vid){
    vid.onloadeddata = function() {
        vid.play(); 
        alert("Browser has loaded the current frame");
    }
}
/*
var video = document.getElementById('vd1');
if(video){
    video.addEventListener('loadeddata', function() {
    video.play();
    });
}*/
</script>

</body> 
</html>
```

But if i pass in pagefinished like below it is working fine.

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        // autoplay when finished loading via javascript injection
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) { mMessageContentView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0].play(); })()"); }
    });
```

so How can i use play event using this script tag in android webview?